# How to run sensitivity analysis of maxent SDM in R?

Tags: r, loop, maxent, dismo

I have been told that I have to run sensitivity analysis on a species distribution model. I cannot find much on this, but I suspect that it means that I would have to re-run the model 999 times, each time using a random subset of the environmental variables which I have used to create the original model. How would I go about doing this in R? I have 7 environmental variables, which I stacked in R using the `stack()` function from the `raster` package, and then made the model using the `maxent()` function from the `dismo` package. I would ideally want to know how make a loop which picks environmental variables from the raster stack randomly, but if that is not possible, how would I make a loop that can re-run the maxent model 999 times and store the distribution of species presence probabilities in such a way that I could compare them to each other?